# Symfony 5 Object Serialization with ManyToMany Relation Times Out

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, orm

In my Symfony 5 application, I have an entity class `Product` which has two properties `$categories` and `$bundles`. The product class has a ManyToMany relation with both the properties. When I comment out either one of the properties the Product serialization works perfectly. But incase both properties are present the serialization times out.

The code excerpt from Product class.

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=ProductBundle::class, mappedBy="products")
     */
    private $productBundles;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, mappedBy="products")
     * @MaxDepth(1)
     */
    private $categories;

}
```

The code for the serialization is below.

```
    $products = $productRepository->findBySearchQuery($name);
    $productsJson = $serializerInterface->serialize($products, 'json', [
        ObjectNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object) {
            return $object->getId();
        }
    ]);
```

I have tried using the @ORM/JoinTable annotation suggested on some other Stackoverflow answers and @MaxDepth as well but no luck. The code works if any of the properties are commented out. Would be grateful for any advice on this.

Comment: don't know if you tried ... but ... "The check is only done if the AbstractObjectNormalizer::ENABLE_MAX_DEPTH key of the serializer context is set to true." source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-serialization-depth ... I'd say that you're trying to serialize "too much" (in amount of memory/runtime) and probably are exporting the whole product database? ^^

Comment: @Jakumi there are only 20 products in my database so I thought that is okay to serialize and the depth part didn't help as well but thank you for pointing it out. But when I return only the names of the products it starts to work. Confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointed out by @Jakumi the serializer was looping over and over the object properties `$categories` and `$bundles`. I avoided that by using the Serialization groups.

The product class

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=ProductBundle::class, mappedBy="products")
     * @Groups("product_listing:read")
     */
    private $productBundles;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, mappedBy="products")
     * @Groups("product_listing:read")
     */
    private $categories;

}
```

The category class

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("product_listing:read")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("product_listing:read")
     */
    private $name;
}
```

The call to serializer

```
$products = $productRepository->findBySearchQuery($name);
$productsJson = $serializerInterface->serialize($products, 'json', ['groups' => 'product_listing:read']);
```

I hope this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

okay, 20 products is actually not much. so I guess you're outputting the same objects over and over again if you let the relations be serialized unhindered.

I actually don't know how to achieve this reliably with the serializer. But the standard ways would just be enough probably. I like serializing via the [`JsonSerializable`](https://php.net/JsonSerializable) interface on your entities like this (omitting the ORM stuff for brevity):

```
class Product implements \JsonSerializable {
    public $name;
    public $categories; // relation

    // getters + setters omitted

    // this implements \JsonSerializable
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'categories' => array_map(function($category) {
                 return $category->jsonSerializeChild();
            }, $this->categories),
        ];
    }

    // this function effectively stops recursion by leaving out relations
    public function jsonSerializeChild() {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

If you implement this on all your entities you can very effectively limit the depth of serialization to two (i.e. the "base" entities and their connected entities).

also, the symfony serializer will use the JsonSerializable interface if it's defined if your serializing *to* JSON. Obviously, this is not as elegant as some fancy annotation-based serialization or a "smart" serializer, that actually manages to stop ... but it'll probably work better...

Comment: You're probably right about the serializer loop over and over on objects with the relations. Thank you for your answer but I found a built-in way inside Symfony to achieve this without writing my own jsonSerialize and jsonSerializeChild function. I will post the answer here if that helps anyone.

Comment: absolutely do! ;o)